# Missing parenthesis cause JavaScript on Firefox to run extremely slow

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

So I've been working on a project and suddenly my animation and everything would run extremely slow. Even my Timeout lagged severeal hundered millisecond behind. Now I've found what caused this, but what I would like to know is why?

This was my original code:

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.width / 2, - 7.5, c.width / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.beginPath();

  // Mark out some path

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore;
```

And then I found I was missing the parenthesis after `restore`:

```
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.width / 2, - 7.5, c.width / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.beginPath();

  // Mark out some path

  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
```

And now it magically works like a charm. Anybody got an idea why? I didn't run into the problem in chrome, I'm on firefox version 53.0.3 (32-Bit).

Oh, by the way, I'm playing an AoudioBufferedSourceNode with a lot of filters during all that, although that kept playing normally.

Comment: It never executed restore in the first piece of your code

Comment: `ctx.save()` saves the current rotation and coordinates of canvas. `ctx.restore()` moves the canvas to the last saved rotation and coordinates. You are not actually moving the canvas, making the maneuver redundant, but it still has to compute the answer, which takes calculation power, which takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code was never restoring the canvas state, so your state stack was growing forever. No surprise that would eventually bog things down. `ctx.restore` is effectively a no-op, it doesn't really do anything*. `ctx.restore()` *calls* the `restore` method on `ctx`.

---

* *(It evaluates the current value of `ctx` and then tries to look up the `restore` property on it...then throws away the value it got [the function reference] rather than doing something with it. So it's not quite a no-op, since it would throw an error if [for instance] `ctx` were `null` or `undefined`, but it doesn't do anything useful.)*

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Any idea why this is only on firefox?

Comment: @AramBecker: Different implementations having different tolerances for the ever-growing state stack is all I can think of.